# Python version 3.3 symplifying variables

Tags: python

```
w=f.readline()
x=f.readline()
y=f.readline()
z=f.readline()
strengthA=float(w)
skillA=float(x)
strengthB=float(y)
skillB=float(z)
```

This is a bit of code that I was wondering if it was possible to make into a simpler code to make it shorter but do the same thing... Thanks

Comment: Removing unwanted newlines would reduce the number of lines to half.

Comment: @thefourtheye Really ?? :) :)

Comment: Well, at least you can do `float(f.readline())` in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
from itertools import islice

strengthA, skillA, strengthB, skillB = map(float, islice(f, 4))
```

`map()` loops over the second argument, calling `float()` on each value. `islice(f, 4)` will produce 4 elements from `f` when looped over, then stops producing more. Together with the tuple-assignment, that means 4 float values are produced to be assigned to the 4 names on the left.

This *does* require that you do **not** use `.readline()` on the file object elsewhere, and only iterate over the object. Iteration uses an internal buffer that `.readline()` does not use, so mixing iteration and `.readline()` will lead to strange results (e.g. skipped file contents). Use `next(f)` instead of `f.readline()` to read a single line, or use looping.

Comment: one thing- what is itertools?

Comment: I added links to the functions used; `itertools` comes with Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lists `list = [float(f.readline()),float(f.readline())]`.

It will capture the newline too, though.

Comment: `float()` doesn't care about whitespace, including newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the intermediary variables (w, x, y, z) and read directly into the final variable:

```
strengthA = float(f.readline())

skillA = float(f.readline())

strengthB = float(f.readline())

skillB = float(f.readline())
```

Answer (score 0):

Making it simpler is a good goal, but it is not necessarily the same as shorter.
In your case, it appears you are handling two pairs of values, so the code (in order to be considered properly pythonic) should express this intention.
How about something along these lines?:

```
def get_strength_and_skill(file):
    return (float(file.readline()), float(file.readline))

strengthA, skillA = get_strength_and_skill(f)
strengthB, skillB = get_strength_and_skill(f)
```

Would that suit your needs?
(Several values in round parens creates a tuple. Assigning a tuple to a comma-separated list of variables unpacks the tuple. Useful frequently. Read up about them in the Python docs.)